# Form side-by-side breaking line in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to show a form side-by-side without success:

https://jsfiddle.net/eo6srkjr/

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <form action="#" role="form" method="post">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Option 1</a>
                </form>
                <form action="#" role="form" method="post">
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Option 2</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on it? Thanks

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/eo6srkjr/1/ ?

Comment: Do you have any css you could post as well? EDIT: NVM, I see it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to make both button side by side I have done so here
https://jsfiddle.net/eo6srkjr/6/

Add this to CSS

```
#test{
float: left;
}

#test2{
float: left;
}
```

Add a div to each button you want to style. Like this

```
<div id="test">
  <form action="#" role="form" method="post">
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Option 1</a>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="test2">
 <form action="#" role="form" method="post">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Option 2</a>
 </form>
</div>
```

If this is not the effect desired, let me know and ill help you accordingly.
Then just style each div accordingly to make it positioned exactly as you want.

Comment: Thanks. With your orientation I came using the bootstrap class `pull-left`. Thanks again.